# Crear JSON con 4 Entidades en android (con GSON)

Tags: android, json, gson

Necesito crear un arreglo con datos que tengo en 4 tablas SQLite, estas 4 tablas tienen sus 4 entidades con sus metodos Getter y Setter, la pregunta es para crear un JSON usando la librerias GSON tendria que crear una entidad con los campos de las 4 clases? ya que necesito que los datos de las 4 tablas vayan como una solo fila.

```
String JSON = gson.toJson(detalle1);
String JSON = gson.toJson(detalle2);
String JSON = gson.toJson(detalle3);
String JSON = gson.toJson(detalle4);
```

Con lo anterior creo un JSON para cada entidad pero necesito por ejemplo que la primera fila de cada entidad vaya en un solo array ya que son campos dependientes a la hora de guardarlos en la base de datos.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. De todos modos, como orientación, ten en cuenta que una clase representa una entidad. Lo puedes pensar en términos de la vida real. Supongamos que tus cuatro tablas son: `Persona, Profesion, Direccion, Ciudad`. En la tabla `Persona` tendrás quizá un `id_profesion, id_direccion`. Eso significa que, en la clase `Persona` deberás tener un campo que sea de la clase `Direccion` y otro que sea de la clase `Profesion`. En la clase `Direccion`
 deberás tener un miembro que sea de la clase `Ciudad`. La cuestión aquí es que escribas un modelo de datos coherente y estructural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo empecé hace poco a trabajar con GSON y modelos de datos algo complejos, con clases relacionadas.

La verdad es que al principio no tenía muy claro cómo hacer las cosas, lo que me ayudó fue salvaguardar íntegro el modelo de datos como lo había diseñado en cada tabla y construir mi JSON conforme a ese modelo, **respetando la realidad de los datos**.

Me permito presentar un modelo un poco largo y complejo, pero que puede ayudar a enfrentar el problema de una forma completa, pues incluye en  muchos puntos datos anidados a más de un nivel.

El JSON que se produce es el siguiente:

```
{
    "breviario": {
        "metaLiturgia": {
            "fecha"  : "Domingo 25 de noviembre del 2018",
            "tiempo" : "TIEMPO ORDINARIO",
            "semana"   : "Semana XXXIV",
            "mensaje": "",
            "salterio": "<small></small>",
            "color": 0,
            "meta":0,
            "idTiempo": "08"
        },
        "santo": {

                "nombre": "",
                "vida": ""
        },

        "visperas": {
            "himno" : {
                "texto": "Oh príncipe absoluto de los siglos,~oh Jesucristo, rey de las naciones:~te confesamos árbitro supremo~de las mentes y de los corazones.§En la tierra te adoran los mortales~y los santos te alaban en el cielo,~unidos a sus voces te aclamamos~proclamándote rey del universo.§Oh Jesucristo, príncipe pacífico:~somete a los espíritus rebeldes,~y haz que encuentren el rumbo los perdidos~y que en un solo aprisco se congreguen.§Para eso pendes de una cruz sangrienta,~y abres en ella tus divinos brazos;~para eso muestras en tu pecho herido~tu ardiente corazón atravesado.§Para eso estás oculto en los altares~tras las imágenes del pan y el vino;~para eso viertes de tu pecho abierto~sangre de salvación para tus hijos.§Por regir con amor el universo,~glorificado seas, Jesucristo,~y que contigo y con tu eterno Padre~también reciba gloria el Santo Espíritu. Amén."
            },
            "salmodia": {
                "tipo":0,
                "salmoCompleto": [
                    {
                        "orden": "1",
                        "antifona": "Se sentará sobre el trono de David para reinar eternamente. Aleluya.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 109, 1-5. 7",
                        "tema": "El Mesías, Rey y Sacerdote",
                        "intro": "Él debe reinar hasta poner~todos sus enemigos bajo sus pies.~(1Co 15, 25)",
                        "parte": "",
                        "salmo": "Oráculo del Señor a mi Señor:_«Siéntate a mi derecha,_y haré de tus enemigos estrado de tus pies.»§Desde Sión extenderá el Señor_el poder de tu cetro:_somete en la batalla a tus enemigos.§«Eres príncipe desde el día de tu nacimiento,_entre esplendores sagrados;_yo mismo te engendré, como rocío,_antes de la aurora.»§El Señor lo ha jurado y no se arrepiente:_«Tú eres sacerdote eterno,_según el rito de Melquisedec.»§El Señor a tu derecha, el día de su ira,_quebrantará a los reyes.§En su camino beberá del torrente,_por eso levantará la cabeza."
                    },

                    {
                        "orden": "2",
                        "antifona": "Tu reinado es un reinado perpetuo, tu gobierno va de edad en edad.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 144, 1-13b",
                        "tema": "",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "",
                        "salmo": "Te ensalzaré, Dios mío, mi rey;_bendeciré tu nombre por siempre jamás._Día tras día te bendeciré_y alabaré tu nombre por siempre jamás.§Grande es el Señor, merece toda alabanza,_es incalculable su grandeza;_una generación pondera tus obras a la otra,_y le cuenta tus hazañas.§Alaban ellos la gloria de tu majestad,_y yo repito tus maravillas;_encarecen ellos tus temibles proezas,_y yo narro tus grandes acciones;_difunden la memoria de tu inmensa bondad,_y aclaman tus victorias.§El Señor es clemente y misericordioso,_lento a la cólera y rico en piedad;_el Señor es bueno con todos,_es cariñoso con todas sus creaturas.§Que todas tus creaturas te den gracias, Señor,_que te bendigan tus fieles;_que proclamen la gloria de tu reinado,_que hablen de tus hazañas;§explicando tus proezas a los hombres,_la gloria y majestad de tu reinado._Tu reinado es un reinado perpetuo,_tu gobierno va de edad en edad."
                    },

                    {
                        "orden": "3",
                        "antifona": "Lleva escrito sobre su manto y en su estandarte este nombre: «Rey de reyes y Señor de señores.» A él la gloria y el poder por los siglos de los siglos.",
                        "ref": "Cántico¦Cf. Ap 19, 1-2. 5-7",
                        "tema": "Las bodas del Cordero",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "",
                        "salmo": "Aleluya._La salvación y la gloria y el poder son de nuestro Dios._⟨ⱤAleluya.⟩_Porque sus juicios son verdaderos y justos._ⱤAleluya, ⟨aleluya⟩.§Aleluya._Alabad al Señor, sus siervos todos._⟨ⱤAleluya.⟩_Los que le teméis, pequeños y grandes._ⱤAleluya, ⟨aleluya⟩.§Aleluya._Porque reina el Señor, nuestro Dios, dueño de todo._⟨ⱤAleluya.⟩_Alegrémonos y gocemos y démosle gracias._ⱤAleluya, ⟨aleluya⟩.§Aleluya._Llegó la boda del Cordero._⟨ⱤAleluya.⟩_Su esposa se ha embellecido._ⱤAleluya, ⟨aleluya⟩."
                    }
                ]},

                "lecturaBreve": {
                    "ref": "1Co 15, 25-28",
                    "texto": "Cristo debe reinar hasta poner todos sus enemigos bajo sus pies. El último enemigo aniquilado será la muerte. Porque Dios ha sometido todas las cosas bajo sus pies. Mas cuando él dice que «todo está sometido», es evidente que se excluye a aquel que ha sometido a él todas las cosas. Cuando hayan sido sometidas a él todas las cosas, entonces también el Hijo se someterá a aquel que ha sometido a él todas las cosas, para que Dios sea todo en todo.",
                    "responsorio": "Tu trono, Señor, permanece para siempre.|Tu cetro real es cetro de rectitud.|Permanece para siempre.|Gloria al Padre, y al Hijo, y al Espíritu Santo.",
                    "forma": 6001230
                },

                "magnificat": {
                    "antifona": "«Me ha sido dado todo poder en el cielo y en la tierra», dice el Señor.",
                    "texto":""
                },

                "preces": {
                    "intro": "Hermanos, adoremos a Cristo Rey, el cual existe antes que todas las cosas, y en quien todas las cosas tienen su razón de ser. Elevemos a él nuestra voz, clamando:|Que venga tu reino, Señor.|Con la confianza que nos da el ser participantes de la realeza de Cristo y coherederos de su reino, elevemos nuestra voz al Padre celestial:",
                    "texto": "Cristo, nuestro rey y pastor, congrega a tus ovejas de todos los puntos de la tierra≠y apaciéntalas en verdes praderas de pastos abundantes.§Cristo, nuestro salvador y nuestro guía, reúne a todos los hombres dentro de tu pueblo santo: sana a los enfermos, busca a los extraviados, conserva a los fuertes,≠haz volver a los que se han alejado, congrega a los dispersos, alienta a los desanimados.§Juez eterno, cuando pongas tu reino en manos de tu Padre, colócanos a tu derecha≠y haz que poseamos el reino que nos ha sido preparado desde la creación del mundo.§Príncipe de la paz, quebranta las armas homicidas≠e infunde en todas las naciones el amor a la paz.§Heredero universal de todas las naciones, haz entrar a la humanidad con todos sus bienes al reino de tu Iglesia que tu Padre te ha dado,≠para que todos, unidos en el Espíritu Santo, te reconozcan como su cabeza.∞Cristo, primogénito de entre los muertos y primicia de los que duermen,≠admite a los fieles difuntos a la gloria de tu resurrección."
                },

                "oracion": "Dios todopoderoso y eterno,~que quisiste restaurar todas las cosas~por tu amado Hijo, Rey del universo,~te pedimos que la creación entera,~liberada de la esclavitud del pecado,~te sirva y te alabe eternamente.~Por nuestro Señor Jesucristo, tu Hijo,~que vive y reina contigo~en la unidad del Espíritu Santo,~y es Dios, por los siglos de los siglos."
            }

    }
}
```

Para hacerlo corto, tomemos algunos ejemplos de este JSON.

Esta parte del JSON representa a la tabla `santo` de la base de datos, la cual tiene dos columnas: `nombre, vida`:

```
   "santo": {

            "nombre": "",
            "vida": ""
    }
```

La clase es así:

```
public class Santo {
    private String nombre;
    private String vida;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getVida() {
        return vida;
    }

    public void setVida(String vida) {
        this.vida = vida;
    }
}
```

Luego, puedes ver un nodo `visperas` mucho más complejo con varios elementos primitivos (cadena, int, etc) y otros elementos que **son de otra clase**. Si observas el nodo, podrás dedudicir que `himno, salmodia, lecturaBreve, magnificat y preces` son clases independientes que a su vez forman parte de `visperas`, mientras que `oracion` es un elemento digamos primitivo (string) que también es parte de vísperas.

La clase `visperas` se presenta por tanto así:

```
public class Visperas {
    private Himno himno;
    private Salmodia salmodia;
    private LecturaBreve lecturaBreve;
    private Magnificat magnificat;
    private Preces preces;
    private String oracion;

    public Himno getHimno() {
        return himno;
    }

    public void setHimno(Himno himno) {
        this.himno = himno;
    }

    public Salmodia getSalmodia() {
        return salmodia;
    }

    public void setSalmodia(Salmodia salmodia) {
        this.salmodia = salmodia;
    }

    public LecturaBreve getLecturaBreve() {
        return lecturaBreve;
    }

    public void setLecturaBreve(LecturaBreve lecturaBreve) {
        this.lecturaBreve = lecturaBreve;
    }

    public Magnificat getMagnificat() {
        return magnificat;
    }

    public void setMagnificat(Magnificat magnificat) {
        this.magnificat = magnificat;
    }

    public Preces getPreces() {
        return preces;
    }

    public void setPreces(Preces preces) {
        this.preces = preces;
    }

    public String getOracion() {
        return oracion;
    }

    public void setOracion(String oracion) {
        this.oracion = oracion;
    }
}
```

Si quieres seguir analizando, puedes ver que dentro del nodo `salmodia` hay todavía otro nodo que es una clase propia, se llama: `salmoCompleto`.

La clase `Salmodia` se presenta así:

```
public class Salmodia {
    public int tipo;
    public List<SalmoCompleto> salmoCompleto;

    /*Un getter super interesante*/
    public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto() {

        for (SalmoCompleto s : salmoCompleto) {
            /*
               *Aquí doy formato a cada elemento del salmo:
                *tema, texto, parte, etc
                *y lo devuelvo formateado
            */      
        }
}
```

Podrás apreciar que `salmocompleto` está definido en `Salmodia` como una lista del tipo `SalmoCompleto`: `List<SalmoCompleto>`

La clase `SalmoCompleto` está definida así:

```
public class SalmoCompleto {
    private String orden;
    private String antifona;
    private String ref;
    private String tema;
    private String intro;
    private String parte;
    private String salmo;

    //getter setter
}
```

Esto es muy interesante y muy útil. Porque por ejemplo yo necesito que cada salmo, sean 3, sean 50, traigan un formato específico. Por decir algo, que el color de letra del miembro `tema` sea en rojo. Pues todo ese trabajo completo lo hago en el método `getSalmoCompleto` de la clase `Salmodia`, la cual me va recorriendo el array de salmos y formateando.

---

### Obtener las referencias

Muestro un ejemplo como obtengo cada referencia de los diferentes nodos de mi JSON:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JSONObject jsonBreviario = jsonDatos.getJSONObject("breviario");
        Breviario breviario = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonBreviario), Breviario.class);
        MetaLiturgia meta = breviario.getMetaLiturgia();
        Santo santo = breviario.getSanto();

        Visperas visperas = breviario.getVisperas();
        Himno himno = visperas.getHimno();
        Salmodia salmodia = visperas.getSalmodia();
        LecturaBreve lecturaBreve = visperas.getLecturaBreve();
        Magnificat magnificat = visperas.getMagnificat();
        Preces preces = visperas.getPreces();
```

Por ejemplo, un proceso que podría ser complicado, como es obtener el salmo completo con diferentes formatos, colores, y tamaños de letra, se hace tan simple como hacer esto:

```
        sb.append(salmodia.getSalmoCompleto());
```

el método hace el resto.

---

### Tener un criterio claro

Al principio estaba un poco perdido con GSON. Mi criterio fue: construir un JSON que respete mi modelo de datos. O sea, si tengo una tabla `himno`, el JSON debe tener un nodo llamado `himno`, si tengo una tabla `visperas`, la cual a su vez usa elementos de otras tablas, mi JSON debe tener un nodo `visperas` y los sub-nodos que haga falta.

De ahí podemos deducir que lo más importante es **estructurar bien tu JSON, respetando tu modelo de datos**. Habría sido aparentemente más fácil no crear un nodo `salmodia` además con un sub-nodo `salmoCompleto` y meter el array de salmos directamente en el nodo principal. Pero resulta que hay otras tablas que también usan `salmodia`, tablas parecidas a `visperas`, pero con otra función. Si yo por (aparente) facilidad saco a `salmoCompleto` del nodo `salmodia` y lo pongo directamente en el nodo `visperas`, no hago otra cosa que irrespetar el diseño de datos (un salmoCompleto es un salmoCompleto), y además me complico la vida cuando tenga que formatear cada elemento del salmo o cuando tenga que usarlo desde otra de las clases que también usan elementos del tipo `SalmoCompleto`.

---

### Una herramienta muy útil

Hay una herramienta que me ayudó mucho a implementar correctamente el modelo de datos. Una vez tengas el JSON construido conforme a tu modelo de datos, lo puedes pegar y te generará la clase de una forma correcta. Se trata de [**`jsonutils`**](https://jsonutils.com), una herramienta en línea que te genera las clases a partir de un JSON. La única crítica que puedo hacerle es que crea los miembros de la clase como `public`, yo en mi caso los cambio a `private` para hacer que el manejo de los miembros pase por los *getter* y los *setter*.

---

### PD:

Espero que esta respuesta te sea de ayuda para tu modelo de datos. Si hay alguna duda puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Comment: Si entiendo es que una clase llamemos la padre puede recibir una lista de objetos de una case hija y retornarla como como una propiedad, digo por tu clase visveperas que pareciera que maneja las demas clases

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez sí, más o menos eso. La lectura correcta hay que hacerla **desde el modelo de datos**, o sea, un objeto o tabla de la clase `Visperas`, tiene uno (o pueden ser más) objetos de la clase `Himno, Salmodia, Preces` etc. Se entiende que hay una tabla `Himno`, una tabla `Preces`... Pero no solo eso, el objeto `Salmodia` tiene una lista de salmos (aquí no hay necesariamente una tabla `Salmodia`, pero si una tabla `Salmo` que contiene todos los miembros de un salmo: tema, salmo(texto), parte, etc.