# Convertir parametro de un POST a un objeto

Tags: java, json

Tengo el siguiente Map en Java:

> {userData={'key':'test', 'att1':'test1', 'att2':'test2'}, userId=string}

Estoy tratando de diseccionarlo y transformar todo el contenido de userData en un objeto Java. pero no estoy lograndolo. Con el metodo get() de la clase Map obtengo de vuelta el contenido de el campo userData. Pero como puedo transformarlo en un objeto?

Ademas la cantidad de parametros que hay en el JSON de userData puede contener desde dos campos(key, att1) hasta tres campos (key,att1, att2).

Alguna ayuda??

Comment: Echale un vistazo a la libreria GSON, te puede servir para converitr JSON a objetos en Java y viceversa. Mira este enlace: [Json to Object Java](https://medium.com/el-acordeon-del-programador/convertir-objetos-java-a-json-y-de-regreso-1077500d78f7)

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es el objeto devuelto por `get("userData")`? Tienes que hacerte un POJO y rellenarlo. Como dice Mario GSON es una opción si quieres meter mas librerias.

Comment: Tengo un objeto que tiene dos parametros uno de ellos es un string donde se almacena el json. El tema es que ese json puede variar el numero de variables que tiene entonces hacer un POJO fijo podria no abarcar todo el numero de variables. Echare un vistazo a la libreria GSON. Gracias ;D

Comment: Te recomendaría, como ha dicho @MarioGuiber, el uso de GSON. Te permitirá mapear una respuesta de tu servicio a cualquier clase que tengas en el modelo de datos y luego tirar de los métodos de la clase para manejar situaciones complejas. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) yo expuse un caso de uso con un JSON más o menos complejo. Está en el contexto de Android, pero sirve también para cualquier otro contexto ya que GSON recibe el objeto de la forma en que se lo suministres y lo mapea a la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un objeto tal que así:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class JsonToObject implements Serializable {

 private String key;
 private String att1;
 private String att2;

 /*Getters & Setters*/
}
```

Y recogerlo desde el body con @RequestBody por ejemplo:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/url")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> metodoDelPost(@RequestBody JsonToObject jsonToObject) throws Exception {}
```

De este modo guardas la respuesta json en un objeto java con el que operar.
Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo!