# Extraer un dato de un Json?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, jsonarray

mi problema es el siguiente tengo un String que tiene el siguiente contenido (fue un respuesta de mi jsonobjrequest)

```
{"Agente":{"general":{"id":"11","nombre":"FREDERICK TOVAR MARAVILLA","correo":"rommeljb@hotmail.com","usuario":"fre","cve":"223838","zona":"1","puesto":"Agente Vial","curp":"","ife":"42342342342","idestado":"14","estado":"Jalisco","municipio":"Guadalajara","sucursal":"GUADALAJARA CENTRO"},"multas":{"hoy":"0","semana":"0","mes":"0"},"consultas":{"hoy":"0","semana":"0","mes":"0"},"servicios":{"hoy":"0","semana":"0","mes":"0"},"cancelaciones":{"hoy":"0","semana":"0","mes":"0"},"imagen":"http:\/\/flexorpoint.mx\/mobilemanager\/img\/agentes\/med\/11.jpg"},"error":"no","msg":"Correcto"}

String Resp = response.getString("Agente");
```

Quiero extrar Solo el index nombre y guardarlo en otro lugar, entiendo que seria algo como:

```
JSONObject object =(JSONObject) json.get(i);//Este esta mal
 String nombre= object.get("nombre").toString(); //
```

pero no acabo de hacer que funcioone que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Primero tienes que sacar el objeto JSON con algo como `JSONObject mJson = response.getJSONObject("Agente");` y luego podrás acceder a las propiedades del mismo por separado, por ejemplo: `String nombre=mJson.getString("nombre");` tienes que aplicar un *getter*  según el tipo de dato que tenga la propiedad del JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He formateado tu objeto con la ayuda de **[`jsonlint`](http://www.jsonlint.com)** para poder analizarlo mejor y decidir cómo tiene que ser leído. Es fundamental ver cómo viene el objeto, si vienen otros objetos JSON anidados en él, como es el caso precisamente.

Veamos el objeto organizado:

```
{
    "Agente": {
        "general": {
            "id": "11",
            "nombre": "F*** *** ***",
            "correo": "sucorreo@elmail.com",
            "usuario": "fre",
            "cve": "2****",
            "zona": "1",
            "puesto": "Agente Vial",
            "curp": "",
            "ife": "42***2",
            "idestado": "14",
            "estado": "Jalisco",
            "municipio": "Guadalajara",
            "sucursal": "GUADALAJARA CENTRO"
        },
        "multas": {
            "hoy": "0",
            "semana": "0",
            "mes": "0"
        },
        "consultas": {
            "hoy": "0",
            "semana": "0",
            "mes": "0"
        },
        "servicios": {
            "hoy": "0",
            "semana": "0",
            "mes": "0"
        },
        "cancelaciones": {
            "hoy": "0",
            "semana": "0",
            "mes": "0"
        },
        "imagen": "http:\/\/flexorpoint.mx\/mobilemanager\/img\/agentes\/med\/99999.jpg"
    },
    "error": "no",
    "msg": "Correcto"
}
```

La cuestión es muy simple.

Tienes un `response` con un objeto JSON cuya clave es `Agente`.

Entonces, tienes que sacar primero el `JSONObject` que hay en `Agente`:

```
JSONObject agenteJSON=response.getJSONObject("Agente");
```

Luego, otra cosa que se observa es que ciertos datos están dentro de otros objetos JSON. Por ejemplo, el `nombre, correo` etc, están dentro de un objeto JSON que se llama `general`.  Entonces, partiendo de `agenteJSON` creado anteriormente, tendrías que crear una referencia a ese otro objeto anidado:

```
JSONObject generalJSON=agenteJSON.getJSONObject("general");
```

Ahora, para acceder a las propiedades de `general` puedes usar algo como:

```
String id=generalJSON.getString("id");
String nombre=generalJSON.getString("nombre");
```

Los *getter*  se usan según el tipo de dato que haya a la derecha. Aquí se usa `getString` porque los valores que hay a la derecha están entre comillas. Si fuera un número, habría que usar `getInt` o si fuera un booleano, usar `getBoolean`. En el caso del `id` es un `string` aunque contenga un `1` dentro, éste está entre comillas.

Nótese que los otros datos también están dentro de sendos objetos JSON (`multas, consultas ...`), debes referenciarlos, partiendo de `agenteJSON`, como hiciste con `general`.

Comment: Gracias ahora entiendo como recibir estas Request <3

Comment: Me alegro, @itsvanmoreno. Por cierto, si usas la librería `GSon` es mucho más fácil: te permite mapear el JSON a tu modelo de datos. O sea, si tuvieras una clase `Agente` con miembros del tipo  `General, Multas, Consultas`  etc mapeas y luego usas los métodos de cada clase en el modelo de datos. Esto es particularmente útil para operaciones complicadas con los datos. Además escribes un código coherente en todo momento que refleja en la App como está organizada la base de datos x ejemplo. [Aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) de un `response` complejo manejado con GSon.

Answer (score 0):

De preferencia mete validaciones en donde pueda ir accediendo a cada parte del código, también declara las variables  y genera los constructores, para poder guardar los datos en caso de que los necesites en una clase posterior

ejemplo

```
   JSONObject response = ClientHttp.callSoapService(urlConsult, request);
//verificamos si esiste envelope, body, getSuscriptorResponse y return
        if (response.has("S:Envelope") && response.getJSONObject("S:Envelope").has("S:Body")
                && response.getJSONObject("S:Envelope").getJSONObject("S:Body").has("ns0:getSuscriptorResponse")
                && response.getJSONObject("S:Envelope").getJSONObject("S:Body").getJSONObject("ns0:getSuscriptorResponse").has("return")) {

            JSONObject returnObject = response.getJSONObject("S:Envelope")
                    .getJSONObject("S:Body")
                    .getJSONObject("ns0:getSuscriptorResponse")
                    .getJSONObject("return");
System.out.println(" --------"+returnObject);

            // validamos si el objeto "return" contiene el objeto "devices"
            if (returnObject.has("devices")) {
                JSONObject devicesObject = returnObject.getJSONObject("devices");
                // validamos si el objeto "devices" contiene la propiedad "userAgent"
                if (devicesObject.has("userAgent")) {
                    String userAgent = devicesObject.getString("userAgent");
                    System.out.println("User Agent: " + userAgent);//---------------------------------------------------

                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se encontró la propiedad 'userAgent' en 'devices'");
                }

                if (devicesObject.has("mac")) {
                    String mac = devicesObject.getString("mac");
                    System.out.println("mac: " + mac);//------------------------------------
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se encontró la propiedad 'userAgent' en 'devices'");
                }
                if (devicesObject.has("esn")) {
                    String esn = devicesObject.getString("esn");
                    System.out.println("esn: " + esn);//------------------------------------
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se encontró la propiedad 'userAgent' en 'devices'");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No se encontró el objeto 'devices' en 'return'");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Estructura de respuesta no válida");
        }

        return response;

            }
```