# Como puedo leer el objecto dentro de un JSON utilizando GSON

Tags: android-studio, gson

Buenas estoy intentando acceder al jSon y dentro de él, al objecto que se llama **idiomas**. ¿Como puedo solamente obtener los parámetros que contenga **idiomas**. Se esta utilizando la Libreria GSON.

```
{
  "decimalHola": 94.55,
  "boleanoHola": true,
  "enteroHola": 123,
  "idiomas": {
    "en": {
      "msg": {
        "titulo": "[EN] Title BLABLABLA",
        "mensaje": "[EN] Menssage, blablabla"
      }
    },
    "es": {
      "msg": {
        "titulo": "[ES] Titulo BLABLABLA",
        "mensaje": "[ES] Mensaje , blablabla"
      }
    }
  },
  "mensajeHola": "Hello World"
}
```

En Android Studio tengo declarado lo siguiente para saber cual es el idioma nativo del dispositivo.
`String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`

La idea es mostrar el titulo y el mensaje dependiendo del idioma que tenga el dispositivo. ¿Como debería de hacerlo correctamente para que funcione?

Comment: Lo interesante de GSon es que con suma facilidad puedes mapear el objeto a una clase y luego usar esa clase para obtener cualquier información dentro de los miembros del JSON. Aquí lo interesante sería saber si tienes una clase `Idiomas` a la cual mapearías esa parte del objeto. Si no la tienes, ¿para qué quieres usar GSon? Por otra parte, viendo el JSON mismo me temo que lo tienes mal organizado, por ejemplo, en `idiomas` deberías tener un array de objetos JSON, a no ser que en la aplicación sólo se vaya a manejar el idioma  `es` y el `en`. Si manejar más idiomas no tienes el diseño idóneo.

Comment: En una app donde uso un modelo de datos complejo, basado en muchas tablas relacionadas entre sí, el uso de Gson me ayudó muchísimo. La cuestión fue diseñar clases que representen cada entidad de mi base de datos, producir en el servidor un JSON organizado según ese modelo y mapearlo usando Gson. Lo interesante es que en las clases puedes implementar manejos verdaderamente complicados y luego llamar los métodos que hacen esos manejos. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) doy un poco más de detalles sobre esto, que es para mi la verdadera ventaja de Gson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con Gson necesitas espejar el formato del json en una clase:

```
{
  "decimalHola": 94.55,
  "boleanoHola": true,
  "enteroHola": 123,
  "idiomas": {
    "en": {
      "msg": {
        "titulo": "[EN] Title BLABLABLA",
        "mensaje": "[EN] Menssage, blablabla"
      }
    },
    "es": {
      "msg": {
        "titulo": "[ES] Titulo BLABLABLA",
        "mensaje": "[ES] Mensaje , blablabla"
      }
    }
  },
  "mensajeHola": "Hello World"
}
```

Equivale a una clase así:

```
public class AppLocalizacion{
  private dobule decimalHola;
  private boolean boleanoHola;
  private int enteroHola;
  private Idiomas idiomas;
  private String mensajeHola;

  // Getters y Setters
}

public class Idiomas{
  private Idioma en;
  private Idioma es;

  // Getters y Setters
}

public class Idioma{
  Msg msg;
  // Getter y Setter
}

public class Msg{
  String titulo;
  String mensaje;
  // Getters y Setters
}
```

Luego para deserializar el mensaje:

suponiendo que el String de json está en una variable `json`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
AppLocalizacion appLocalizacion = gson.fromJson(json, AppLocalizacion.class);

Idiomas idiomas = appLocalizacion.getIdiomas();

String tituloEnIngles = idiomas.getEn().getMsg().getTitulo();
```

Como dijo @A.Cedano, esta estructura del json no te permite tener más idiomas sin tener que modificar la clase, para agregar otro Idioma (por ejemplo 'pt').

Esto es porque cada key del json es un atributo de la clase java.

Sería diferente si la key fuera fija ("idiomas") y el valor fuera un array con las definiciones. En ese caso los valores se levantarían en una lista.

Por ultimo, otras librerías como Jackson son una mejor opción para este tipo de json con keys dinámicos.