# Gson devuelve double y no integer

Tags: java, json, gson

Estoy teniendo el problema que GSON me esta devolviendo los integer en double, y esto hace que en mi aplicacion se vea "precio": 109.0, cuando debería ser unicamente "109".

Os cuento, desde la aplicación principal, se llama a un servicio, este servicio es el que monta todo el JSON y lo devuelve a la aplicación principal como un string:

```
String responseJson = restTemplateApp.getForObject(url.toString(), String.class);
```

El string responseJson, tiene todo el JSON de respuesta, por ejemplo este:

```
{ 
   "status":200,
   "data":{ 
      "cards":[ 
         { 
            "last_digits":"7352",
            "masked_number":"XXXXXXXXXXXX7352",
            "id":"25255252525BBB",
            "description":"CCC",
            "balance":0,
            "balance_expire":0,
            "description_all":"CCC",
            "url_img":"URL",
            "state":"INACTIVA",
            "qr_code":"25235WWGW252GF",
            "expiration_date":"2524518000",
            **"id_collective":1019,**
            "id_cif":"WFWFSDF",
            **"bin":11111,**
            "flagVirtual":"S",
            "flagEshabitual":"S",
            "flagCollective":"S",
            "esHabitual":{ 
               "nconc":"55555",
               "nombre":"A",
               "country":"B",
               "province":"C",
               "town":"D"
            }
```

Como podeis ver, en el objeto los campos "BIN" e "idCollective" son numeros enteros.

Bien, despues este string se transforma con el GSON, ya que el servicio devuelve el siguiente objeto DataResponse >, por tanto lo transformamos así:

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(responseJson, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
    payload.setData(map);
return payload;
```

Y al final, lo que devuelve el servicio es el siguiente JSON.. como podeis ver los integer los transforma a double y le añade el ".0", y es incorrecto.

¿Hay alguna forma de que el gson me devuelva los enteros tal cual?

```
{ 
       "status":200,
       "data":{ 
          "cards":[ 
             { 
                "last_digits":"7352",
                "masked_number":"XXXXXXXXXXXX7352",
                "id":"25255252525BBB",
                "description":"CCC",
                "balance":0.0,
                "balance_expire":0.0,
                "description_all":"CCC",
                "url_img":"URL",
                "state":"INACTIVA",
                "qr_code":"25235WWGW252GF",
                "expiration_date":"2524518000",
                **"id_collective":1019.0,**
                "id_cif":"WFWFSDF",
                **"bin":11111.0,**
                "flagVirtual":"S",
                "flagEshabitual":"S",
                "flagCollective":"S",
                "esHabitual":{ 
                   "nconc":"55555",
                   "nombre":"A",
                   "country":"B",
                   "province":"C",
                   "town":"D"
                }
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Puede que el problema esté en la clase `TypeToken`. Supongo que estás mapeando el JSON a esa clase. ¿Podrías mostrar esa clase? Es más, deberías tener una clase `Cards`, para que el mapeo se haga de forma simple y automática ([ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967)), en cuyo caso deberías mirar en esa clase.

Comment: Buenas Cedano gracias por contestar.

Te indico que la clase TypeToken es propia de Gson.

Sobre lo de tener la clase cards, creo que no haria falta, ya que todo el JSON que recibimos es un String, y lo que hace con el GSON es pasarlo a un map de "String-Object" para así finalmente mostrar el JSON.

He estado leyendo que en la libreria de GSON, hay una clase interna que tiene que cuando es un NUMBER devuelva un double, por tanto siempre que vaya a mapear el number lo pasa a double y aquí está el problema.

Comment: Parece que es cierto eso que dices, yo no lo sabía ([ver esta pregunta y las respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15507997/5587982)). La solución parece más complicada que tener tu propia clase `Cards` y hacer un mapeo directo del resultado a esa clase. Para mi es una utilidad potente de Gson por lo explicado en el enlace de mi último comentario. Pero eso ya depende de ti. Es una pena no sacar ventaja de esa potencialidad de Gson. Sería cuestión de definir una clase, que se puede hacer incluso con el mismo JSON y mapear la respuesta JSON a ella, usando luego los *getter*.