# Spinner con Volley y obtener id ANDROID

Tags: java, android, spinner, volley

Necesito obtener el id al seleccionar un item en el componente spinner, en el spinner solo quiero mostrar el nombre, es decir tengo un arreglo {54-gato}, {80-perro}, solo quiero que devuelva el ID y muestre solo el nombre en el spinner. Por favor me pueden ayudar, gracias.

```
String url = "http://xxxx/bewild/api/v1/consulta/especie/";

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("especie");

            Log.e("Json array de especie: ", String.valueOf(mJsonArray));

            for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("JsonObject en for", String.valueOf(mJsonObject));

                ArrayList<JSONObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                lista.add(mJsonObject);

                id = mJsonObject.getString("id");

                name = mJsonObject.getString("nombre_comun");

                arreglo.add(name);
            }
            spinneronly.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, arreglo));

            Log.e("Array en Volley: ", String.valueOf(arreglo));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: name  obtiene  por ejemplo "{54-gato}" ? agrega que formato tiene la consulta, un ejemplo.

Comment: Este es mi json: {
  "error": false,
  "especie": [
    {
      "id": 70,
      "descripcion": "Sciurus vulgari",
      "nombre_comun": "ardilla  ",
      "id_tipoespecie": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 82,
      "descripcion": "Sciurus vulgari",
      "nombre_comun": "ardilla",
      "id_tipoespecie": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 108,
      "descripcion": "Sciurus stramineus",
      "nombre_comun": "ardilla",
      "id_tipoespecie": 3
    }  ] }

Comment: Con el codigo que coloque en el problema en arreglo.add(name) obtengo solo el nombre del arreglo y bueno por una parte estaria bien, pero lo que deseo es que muestre en el spinner el nombre pero me devuelva el id de ese item. Por ejemplo escojo "gato y me devuelve el id 50"

Comment: El problema es que en la estructura de datos tendrías que meter los dos valores: el `id` y `nombre_comun` para luego poder sacar uno en base al otro. Quizá para este caso convendría usar un `HashMap` dentro del ArrayList en vez de un simple `String` con el cual no podrás hacerlo. Otra posibilidad insteresante para casos como estos es usar la librería GSon y mapear el JSON a una clase `Animal`, así, llenarías tu lista con objetos de la clase `Animal` y luego usarías los *getter* de esa clase para obtener el dato que te interesa. [Aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener el valor de "nombre_comun" puedes eliminar los caracteres numericos y el caracter "-", de esta forma:

```
name = mJsonObject.getString("nombre_comun").replaceAll("\\d", "").replace("-","");
```

de esta forma obtendrías cada elemento sin el numero ni el guión:

```
{gato}, {perro},
```

Comment: Este es mi json: { "error": false, "especie": [ { "id": 70, "descripcion": "Sciurus vulgari", "nombre_comun": "ardilla ", "id_tipoespecie": 3 }, { "id": 82, "descripcion": "Sciurus vulgari", "nombre_comun": "ardilla", "id_tipoespecie": 3 }, { "id": 108, "descripcion": "Sciurus stramineus", "nombre_comun": "ardilla", "id_tipoespecie": 3 } ] }

Comment: Con el codigo que coloque en el problema en arreglo.add(name) obtengo solo el nombre del arreglo y bueno por una parte estaria bien, pero lo que deseo es que muestre en el spinner el nombre pero me devuelva el id de ese item. Por ejemplo escojo "gato y me devuelve el id 50"