# Como parsear JSON con GSON Multi Nivel

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Estoy intentando mostrar en Android Studio un arreglo en jSON. Estoy utilizando la libreria GSON, para que resulte mas sencillo. Pero me he quedado bloqueado o en blanco y no se como seguir avanzado. Extraigo correctamente el primer parametro: **geometryType**. Pero necesito sacar de la ultima linea del multinivel, los siguiente datos: **Country_Region, Last_Update, Confirmed, Deaths y Recovered**.

Puedo sacar el primer nivel del JSON, pero ya me pierdo para profundizar en mas niveles. ¿Como es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

**JSON**

```
    {  
  "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326,
    "latestWkid": 4326
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "OBJECTID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
      "alias": "OBJECTID",
      "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
      "domain": null,
      "defaultValue": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Province_State",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Province/State",
      "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
      "length": 8000,
      "domain": null,
      "defaultValue": null
    }
  ],
  "features": [   
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 32,
        "Province_State": "Taiwan",
        "Country_Region": "Taiwan",
        "Last_Update": 1582719784000,
        "Lat": 23.7,
        "Long_": 121,
        "Confirmed": 32,
        "Deaths": 1,
        "Recovered": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 79,
        "Province_State": null,
        "Country_Region": "Bahrain",
        "Last_Update": 1582656932000,
        "Lat": 26.0275,
        "Long_": 50.55,
        "Confirmed": 23,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 18,
        "Province_State": null,
        "Country_Region": "Malaysia",
        "Last_Update": 1582545182000,
        "Lat": 2.5,
        "Long_": 112.5,
        "Confirmed": 22,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 18
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 90,
        "Province_State": null,
        "Country_Region": "Germany",
        "Last_Update": 1582675389000,
        "Lat": 51,
        "Long_": 9,
        "Confirmed": 18,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 14
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Aquí tengo mi Clase: GENERAL_B**

```
public class GENERAL_B{
    private String geometryType;

    public String getGeometryType() {
        return geometryType;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.JAVA**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Object Attributes;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Cargamos Libreria
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("Mi_URL_AQUI_JSON")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String json = response.body().string();
                Gson gson = new Gson();

            final GENERAL_B gen = gson.fromJson(json, GENERAL_B.class);
                    Log.d("Mensaje", gen.getGeometryType());


//QUIERO MOSTRAR en un LOG.d: [Country_Region, Last_Update, Confirmed, Deaths y Recovered].

        }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }}
```

Comment: Lo interesante de Gson es que tengas un modelo de datos (Clases) a las que el objeto recibido (JSON) se pueda acoplar. Eso significa que en tu clase debería haber un miembro (`features`) que sería un `List` de objetos del tipo `attributes`. Cuando haces eso y mapeas el JSON a la clase general, ya puedes usar los métodos de esa clase para obtener los datos. **La clave** es dar coherencia al JSON y al modelo de datos. [Mira si esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) te puede ayudar a aclarar el concepto. Si entiendes eso, obtendrás todas las ventajas de Gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases necesarias son:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class EsriGeometryPoint implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("geometryType")
    @Expose
    private String geometryType;
    @SerializedName("spatialReference")
    @Expose
    private SpatialReference spatialReference;
    @SerializedName("fields")
    @Expose
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    @SerializedName("features")
    @Expose
    private List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -57044234498482941L;

    public String getGeometryType() {
        return geometryType;
    }

    public void setGeometryType(String geometryType) {
        this.geometryType = geometryType;
    }

    public SpatialReference getSpatialReference() {
        return spatialReference;
    }

    public void setSpatialReference(SpatialReference spatialReference) {
        this.spatialReference = spatialReference;
    }

    public List<Field> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(List<Field> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(List<Feature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

}


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Feature implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private Attributes attributes;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 6636177199421449730L;

    public Attributes getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Attributes implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("OBJECTID")
    @Expose
    private String oBJECTID;
    @SerializedName("Province_State")
    @Expose
    private Object provinceState;
    @SerializedName("Country_Region")
    @Expose
    private String countryRegion;
    @SerializedName("Last_Update")
    @Expose
    private String lastUpdate;
    @SerializedName("Lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("Long_")
    @Expose
    private String _long;
    @SerializedName("Confirmed")
    @Expose
    private String confirmed;
    @SerializedName("Deaths")
    @Expose
    private String deaths;
    @SerializedName("Recovered")
    @Expose
    private String recovered;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 5121520135737124730L;

    public String getOBJECTID() {
        return oBJECTID;
    }

    public void setOBJECTID(String oBJECTID) {
        this.oBJECTID = oBJECTID;
    }

    public Object getProvinceState() {
        return provinceState;
    }

    public void setProvinceState(Object provinceState) {
        this.provinceState = provinceState;
    }

    public String getCountryRegion() {
        return countryRegion;
    }

    public void setCountryRegion(String countryRegion) {
        this.countryRegion = countryRegion;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLong() {
        return _long;
    }

    public void setLong(String _long) {
        this._long = _long;
    }

    public String getConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(String confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public String getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public void setDeaths(String deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    public String getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public void setRecovered(String recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Field implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("alias")
    @Expose
    private String alias;
    @SerializedName("sqlType")
    @Expose
    private String sqlType;
    @SerializedName("domain")
    @Expose
    private Object domain;
    @SerializedName("defaultValue")
    @Expose
    private Object defaultValue;
    @SerializedName("length")
    @Expose
    private int length;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -6311716224407000787L;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getSqlType() {
        return sqlType;
    }

    public void setSqlType(String sqlType) {
        this.sqlType = sqlType;
    }

    public Object getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(Object domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public Object getDefaultValue() {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public void setDefaultValue(Object defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SpatialReference implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("wkid")
    @Expose
    private int wkid;
    @SerializedName("latestWkid")
    @Expose
    private int latestWkid;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -5304181045052712104L;

    public int getWkid() {
        return wkid;
    }

    public void setWkid(int wkid) {
        this.wkid = wkid;
    }

    public int getLatestWkid() {
        return latestWkid;
    }

    public void setLatestWkid(int latestWkid) {
        this.latestWkid = latestWkid;
    }
}
```

Y en este caso he creado un main para testearlo. Aquí el ejemplo:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 *
 * @author fernando.alvarez
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String json = "{\"geometryType\":\"esriGeometryPoint\",\"spatialReference\":{\"wkid\":4326,\"latestWkid\":4326},\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"OBJECTID\",\"type\":\"esriFieldTypeOID\",\"alias\":\"OBJECTID\",\"sqlType\":\"sqlTypeOther\",\"domain\":null,\"defaultValue\":null},{\"name\":\"Province_State\",\"type\":\"esriFieldTypeString\",\"alias\":\"Province/State\",\"sqlType\":\"sqlTypeOther\",\"length\":8000,\"domain\":null,\"defaultValue\":null}],\"features\":[{\"attributes\":{\"OBJECTID\":32,\"Province_State\":\"Taiwan\",\"Country_Region\":\"Taiwan\",\"Last_Update\":1582719784000,\"Lat\":23.7,\"Long_\":121,\"Confirmed\":32,\"Deaths\":1,\"Recovered\":5}},{\"attributes\":{\"OBJECTID\":79,\"Province_State\":null,\"Country_Region\":\"Bahrain\",\"Last_Update\":1582656932000,\"Lat\":26.0275,\"Long_\":50.55,\"Confirmed\":23,\"Deaths\":0,\"Recovered\":0}},{\"attributes\":{\"OBJECTID\":18,\"Province_State\":null,\"Country_Region\":\"Malaysia\",\"Last_Update\":1582545182000,\"Lat\":2.5,\"Long_\":112.5,\"Confirmed\":22,\"Deaths\":0,\"Recovered\":18}},{\"attributes\":{\"OBJECTID\":90,\"Province_State\":null,\"Country_Region\":\"Germany\",\"Last_Update\":1582675389000,\"Lat\":51,\"Long_\":9,\"Confirmed\":18,\"Deaths\":0,\"Recovered\":14}}]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        EsriGeometryPoint prueba = gson.fromJson(json, EsriGeometryPoint.class);        
        for(Feature r: prueba.getFeatures()){
            System.out.println(r.getAttributes().getLong());
        }


    }

}
```

El objeto  EsriGeometryPoint sera un objecto con la estructura del Json. Bastará recorrerlo para obtener la información necesaria.

El Output es:

```
121
50.55
112.5
9
```

Las clases las cree [Aqui](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo los objetos creados a partir de ese json.

Puedes usar esta pagina para convertir un json a una clase.

> http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class SpatialReference
{
    public int wkid { get; set; }
    public int latestWkid { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string sqlType { get; set; }
    public object domain { get; set; }
    public object defaultValue { get; set; }
    public int? length { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public int OBJECTID { get; set; }
    public string Province_State { get; set; }
    public string Country_Region { get; set; }
    public object Last_Update { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long_ { get; set; }
    public int Confirmed { get; set; }
    public int Deaths { get; set; }
    public int Recovered { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string geometryType { get; set; }
    public SpatialReference spatialReference { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```