# obtener datos de una url en java

Tags: java, json, web, http, https

tengo una duda espero puedan ayudarme, soy nuevo en esto de las url con java y por ello no comprendo muy bien,quisiera almacenar los datos de un url el cual me responde con unos datos,esos datos los necesito guardan por separado ,por ejemplo "nombre del sensor","dato","timestamp", y como se repiten en 5 ocasiones necesitaba saber como ir los separado y como guardarlos en varias variables y almacenar los datos, en mi intento de recuperar los datos hice esto, funciona!, pero solo me arroja todo los datos de una sola vez.

```
public class h {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         // Se abre la conexión
         URL url = new URL("https://tectuinnoweb.uc.r.appspot.com/api/quiero-datos?cant=5&d=25&format=json&key=b0899ba1d24daa20542589c0f521bb1b14688d59&s=1");
         URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
         conexion.connect();
         
         // Lectura
         InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         String datos = br.readLine();
        
          System.out.println(datos);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

impresion json

[{"nombre_sensor":"sensor_1","dato":758.0,"timestamp":"2020-06-17T03:25:42.181136-05:00"},{"nombre_sensor":"sensor_1","dato":758.0,"timestamp":"2020-06-17T03:25:30.275364-05:00"},{"nombre_sensor":"sensor_1","dato":825.0,"timestamp":"2020-06-17T03:25:18.365076-05:00"},{"nombre_sensor":"sensor_1","dato":658.0,"timestamp":"2020-06-17T03:25:06.519390-05:00"},{"nombre_sensor":"sensor_1","dato":619.0,"timestamp":"2020-06-17T03:24:44.337922-05:00"}]

Comment: Eso depende de la **estructura** que tenga el JSON, es decir según cómo venga organizado podrás leerlo de una forma o de otra. Si quieres facilitar el trabajo te recomiendo que uses la librería Gson, que te permite **mapear**  un JSON a una clase, así, pones en la clase los métodos que necesites y luego vas sobre ruedas, es pura magia, porque los procesos complejos los reflejas en cada clase del modelo y luego en cada contexto sólo invocas los métodos que necesites. [Aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) de cosas que puedes hacer con Gson.

Comment: y que imprime como datos en :   System.out.println(datos); creo que es importante agregues esa información

Comment: ya actualice la pulblicacion :)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estás recibiendo un documento json (a propósito, pude usar el URL para leer los datos, deberías editar el código para remover el key del URL).

Hay muchas maneras de leer JSON en java, la más conocida quizá sea usando Jackson. Primero debes crear una clase con los datos que esperas de tu Json, algo así:

```
public class Sensor {

   private String nombreSensor;
   private String dato;
   private Date timestamp;

   //getters and setters

}
```

Luego, cuando lees el documento json remoto:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//JSON URL to Java object
List<Sensor> sensors = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://tectuinnoweb.uc.r.appspot.com/api/quiero-datos..."), Sensor.class);
```

Esto lo escribí al vuelo así que puede haber detalles, te recomiendo que leas la documentación de Jackson, porque algunas veces necesitas tener un constructor, o agregar alguna anotación para adaptar el documento json original con tu clase.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson