# Mapear tres Clases(Objetos) con JSON solo se Mapea una clase

Tags: java

Tengo 3 clases llamadas `CUsuarioVO,Rol y Area` recibo un json con subObjetos los cuales son Rol y Area, al mapear la clase se llena bien mis atributos de usuario pero las de area y rol quedan en null el json es el siguiente:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "nombres": "Jonny Alejandro",
    "apellidos": "Garcia Sánchez",
    "telefono": "3059006868",
    "corrreo": "jonnyal96@gmail.com",
    "correoalternativo": null,
    "foto": "fotodefecto.png",
    "estado": 1,
    "rolId": 2,
    "arId": 2,
    "Rol": {
        "idrol": 2,
        "cargo": "Director"
    },
    "Area": {
        "idarea": 2,
        "area": "Marketing y desarrollo"
    }
}
```

Clase `CUsuarioVO` con las clases(Objetos) Rol y Area.
la clase area y rol ya tienen sus atributos:

AREA YA TIENE GETTER Y SETTER

```
public class Area {
    
    private long idarea;
    private String area;
```

ROL TIENE SUS GETTER Y SETTER

```
public class Rol {

    private long idrol;
    private String cargo;
```

```
public class CUsuarioVO {
    
    // Estos ya tiene sus getter y setter pero esos si se mapean con el JSON
    private long id;
    private String nombres, apellidos, telefono, corrreo, correoalternativo, foto, estado, rolId, arId;

    //---- OBJETOS DE LAS OTRAS DOS CLASES

    private Area Area;
    private Rol Rol;

    public Area getArea() {
        return Area;
    }

    public void setArea(Area Area) {
        this.Area = Area;
    }

    public Rol getRol() {
        return Rol;
    }

    public void setRol(Rol Rol) {
        this.Rol = Rol;
    }

    //----
```

Código cliente:

```
 private static final ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
 private  static  final  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@GetMapping("/usuario/{id}")
    private void consultarUsuario(@PathVariable long id) {
        try {
           
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(rutaUsuarios + "/consultar/" + id, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
// Asi tampoco mapea Rol y Area: ResponseEntity<CUsuarioVO> respons = restTemplate.exchange(rutaUsuarios + "/consultar/" + id, //HttpMethod.GET, null, CUsuarioVO.class);

            if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                logger.info(response.getBody());
                CUsuarioVO us = objMap.readValue(response.getBody(), CUsuarioVO.class);

            } else if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
                logger.info("Sin informacion");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR AL CONSUMIR API:  " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Con [tag:Jackson]?

Comment: Si con esta: import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; que es mi instancia de ObjectMapper

Comment: Tienes que poner las anotaciones adecuadas en la clase POJO, así como los setter y getter para cada propiedad. [Mira aquí un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073120/5587982). Yo [estoy usando Gson](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) en un proyecto Android con JSON más o menos complejos donde ciertas partes son a su vez clases y funciona perfectamente. Gson me parece mucho más práctico y más claro, sin tantas anotaciones ni historias.