# Obtener un array de objetos a partir de un archivo JSON en JAVA usando org.json

Tags: java, json

Lo unico que quiero hacer es obtener un array de objetos a partir de el fichero JSON que tengo. Tengo importada la librería "org.json". Pero no termino de entender ninguno de los ejemplos que encuentro en internet. Debe de haber una forma simple de hacerlo...

```json
 {"Pizza": [  
    {
        "nombre": "Barbacoa",
        "masa": "Artesana",
        "ingredientes": [ "Tomate", "Queso", "Jamón", "Bacon", "Cebolla", "Ternera", "Salsa BBQ"],
        "precio": 6.50
    },
    { 
        "nombre": "4 quesos",
        "masa": "Fina",
        "ingredientes": [ "queso", "queso", "queso", "queso"],
        "precio": 5.50
    },
    { 
        "nombre": "Rafaleña",
        "masa": "Gorda",
        "ingredientes": [ "Cocaína", "Marihuana", "Colillas", "Queso" ],
        "precio": 10
    }

]}
```

```java
public class Pizzeria {
    

    public void mostrarInicioPrograma() {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la Pizzeria Cris");
        System.out.println("*****************************");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String archivo = "./menu.json";
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(archivo);
        System.out.println(array);

    }

}
```

Comment: La mejor librería que existe para lo que quieres hacer es Gson. Te permite mapear un JSON a una o más clases de tu modelo de datos. Pero conviene que tengas clara una cosa: las clases del modelo van por un lado y los métodos circunstanciales (como el método `main` y otros) deben ir en otra clase. Lo digo porque veo tu método `main` dentro de la clase `Pizzeria`. Este es un gravísimo error de diseño. Otra cosa, conviene que tus clases se llamen como se llama cada nodo del JSON. Si el nodo se llama `Pizza`, tu clase debe llamarse también `Pizza` (sobre todo por claridad y coherencia)...

Comment: ... aunque ese nodo, al tener una lista de objetos (que serían del tipo `Pizza` supongo) debería llamarse más bien `Pizzeria`, no `Pizza`. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo más o menos complejo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) donde se usa Gson para mapear datos. Algo muy interesante es que si el JSON tiene objetos anidados, Gson te mapeará también esos objetos anidados. En el JSON que muestras en la pregunta, podrías tener un objeto `Pizzeria` con una propiedad del tipo `List<Pizza>`  y Gson te creará una lista de objetos del tipo `Pizza`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberas leer el contenido del archivo en String usando tu metodo favorito.
Luego ese String o cuerpo del archivo lo usas para instanciar un objeto JSONObject.
Del objeto puedes obtener el atributo que hace referencia al Array que necesitas, en ese caso "Pizza".

Debes importar

```java
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.json.*;
```

El codigo deberia lucir algo asi (cuerpo del metodo main):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String archivo = "./menu.json";
    try{
        String contenido = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(archivo) ) );
        JSONObject menu = new JSONObject(contenido);
        JSONArray pizzas = menu.getJSONArray("Pizza");
        for(int i = 0; i < pizzas.length() -1 ; i++){
            System.out.println(pizzas.get(i));
        } 

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Espero esto te ayude, saludos.

PD: Lo probe con la version de org.json 20220320 y java 11.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo conseguí ¡¡