# Como se pasan datos de un json a un constructor para q los guarde en getter y setters en java?

Tags: java, json, api

Aqui saco los datos del json de una url

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();

for (String  nombre: nombres) {
     
      JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
      JSONObject jsname = jsondata.getJSONObject(nombre);
      
      System.out.println( "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.10.1/img/champion/"+nombre+".png");
      System.out.println(jsname.get("name"));
      System.out.println(jsname.get("title"));
          
      }
}
```

Entonces quiero pasar esos datos a un constructor con los getter y setter para guardarlos ahi y llamarlos en otra parte.
Ayuda por favor

EDIT

Esta es la clase donde queiro gaurdar los datos generados anteriormente
public class Campeones {

}

PErdon estoy muy perdido

Comment: Con librerías como [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) tú puedes mapear el JSON directamente a instancias del objeto del modelo de datos con una sola línea de código y luego usar esas instancias. [Aquí tienes un tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization) donde se explica lo básico, con algunos ejemplos.

Comment: ya lo tengo asi, y se sacarlo asi el problema es q el json es extenso y complicado

Comment: ¿Y que te lo impide? ¿Donde está la clase que quieres instanciar? No pusiste el código.

Comment: ahi lo he puesto

Comment: Precisamente, mientras más compllicado sea el JSON mayor provecho sacarás de librerías como Gson. En objetos anidados por ejemplo, **basta con mapear al objeto principal** y luego, en la instancia de ese objeto puedes crear métodos para obtener las propiedades de los hijos. La clave de todo es que diseñes correctamente en el modelo, acorde a la estructura del JSON. Mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216798/29967) donde explico con un ejemplo cómo trabajar con un JSON complejo.

Comment: puedo contactar contigo por algun sitio jaime??

Comment: Gracias, pero me gustaria una respuesta personalizada, em corre mucha prisa